# 1) fetch data 2) subscribe to updates. How to not lose updates occuring between 1 and 2 when using pubsub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, publish-subscribe

For example, let's say I have a single-page Sign Up List web application backed by a database with SIGN_UPS Table having NAME (string) and CREATED_AT (timestamp) columns. The page just shows a list of names, being as close to in-synch with the database as reasonably possible.

1. Upon loading, it fetches the existing list of names
2. Through a websocket, it subscribes to be notified when names are added/removed.

Is there a way for this pattern to work? Maybe there is a common name for this problem but I don't know it because I am new to web development. (so it proved tough to search for)

The only solution I have come up with so far is to reverse the order... subscribe first and then fetch, dropping results from the fetch which were retrieved via pubsub (possibly taking advantage of the timestamp column to restrict the SELECT). If this is actually the way to go, is there a typical ways of implementing it with the actual platform I am using (e.g. something based on timestamps so pre-connection messages would be received)? Ruby on Rails + websocket-rails + redis

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single operation named "fetch and subscribe", where requester fetch the data and it is automatically subscribed for changes. It is called implicit subscription.